# Kafka SASL handshake takes too long

Tags: c#, security, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

**Description:** 
authentication using SASL/SCRAM or SASL/PLAINTEXT takes around 9 seconds to complete. *Is this normal?*

**How to reproduce:**

- One Kafka broker instance (v1.1.0)
- One C# producer (Confluent Kafka Client v0.11.4) that does the following:

```
       

    var producerConfig =    
               PropertiesUtils.ReadPropertiesFile("producer.properties");

           using (var producer = new Producer(producerConfig, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
           {
               while (true)
               {
                   Console.Write("message: ");
                   string msg = Console.ReadLine();

                   producer.ProduceAsync("test-topic", null, msg);
               }
           }
```

- One C# consumer (Confluent Kafka Client v0.11.4) that does the following:

```
        

    var config = PropertiesUtils.ReadPropertiesFile("consumer.properties");

            using (var consumer = new Consumer(config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
            {
                consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg)
                      =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.Value);
                };

                consumer.OnError += (_, error)
                  => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");

                consumer.OnConsumeError += (_, msg)
                  => Console.WriteLine($"Consume error ({msg.TopicPartitionOffset}): {msg.Error}");

                consumer.Subscribe("test-topic");

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        consumer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

- server.properties:

  > broker.id=0
  >   num.network.threads=3
  >   num.io.threads=8
  >
  > socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
  >   socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
  >   socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
  >   session.timeout.ms=1000
  >
  > group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
  >
  > listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9093
  >
  > ssl.keystore.type =JKS
  >   ssl.keystore.location=...
  >   ssl.keystore.password=...
  >   ssl.key.password=...
  >
  > ssl.truststore.type=JKS
  >   ssl.truststore.location=...
  >   ssl.truststore.password=...
  >
  > ssl.protocol=TLS
  >   ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
  >   ssl.client.auth=required
  >   security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
  >   ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
  >
  > sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256
  >   sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
  >
  > log.dirs=...
  >   num.partitions=1
  >   num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
  >
  > offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
  >   transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
  >   transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
  >
  > log.retention.hours=168
  >   log.retention.bytes=1073741824
  >   log.segment.bytes=1073741824
  >   log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
  >   num.replica.fetchers=1
  >
  > zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
  >   zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
  >   group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
- consumer.properties:

  > bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
  >   group.id=test-consumer-group
  >   fetch.min.bytes=1
  >   fetch.wait.max.ms=1
  >   auto.offset.reset=latest
  >   socket.blocking.max.ms=1
  >   fetch.error.backoff.ms=1
  >   ssl.ca.location=...
  >   ssl.certificate.location=...
  >   ssl.key.location=...
  >   ssl.key.password=..
  >   security.protocol=SASL_SSL
  >   sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN
  >   sasl.username=...
  >   sasl.password=...
- producer.properties

  > bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
  >   compression.type=none
  >   linger.ms=0
  >   retries=0 acks=0
  >
  > ssl.ca.location=...
  >   ssl.certificate.location=...
  >   ssl.key.location=...
  >   ssl.key.password=...
  >
  > security.protocol=SASL_SSL
  >   sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN
  >   sasl.username=...
  >   sasl.password=...
- Run the consumer. It takes approximately 9 seconds to finish the SASL handshake from request to completion. Here's the log:

  > [2018-07-06 17:03:37,673] DEBUG Set SASL server state to HANDSHAKE_OR_VERSIONS_REQUEST (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:37,673] DEBUG Handling Kafka request API_VERSIONS (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:37,673] DEBUG Set SASL server state to HANDSHAKE_REQUEST (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:37,673] DEBUG Handling Kafka request SASL_HANDSHAKE (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:**37**,674] DEBUG Using SASL mechanism 'PLAIN' provided by client (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:**46**,805] DEBUG Set SASL server state to AUTHENTICATE (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)
  >   [2018-07-06 17:03:46,807] DEBUG Set SASL server state to COMPLETE (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerAuthenticator)

**Remarks**:

- I observed the same duration when running the producer as well
- I observed the same duration when authenticating using SCRAM-256
- I observed the same duration when running Java clients (`kafka-console-consumer` and `kafka-console-producer`)

**UPDATE:**
As recommended by [@edenhill](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/564#issuecomment-405870418) When I setup the broker on an Ubuntu virtual machine and connected the clients from Windows, the latency is no longer observed. I wonder why the SSL handshake and SASL authentication each take 10 seconds on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same problem and I could resolve it by advertising the brokers using fully qualified domain names.

If the brokers are avertised by IP adresses this causes a reverse DNS lookup via `java.net.InetAddress#getHostName()` which is slow on some environments. The relevant code is here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.3.1/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/network/SaslChannelBuilder.java#L231